# Is it necessary to use async keyword when using IDisposable in F#?

Tags: wcf, f#, async-await, idisposable

I get a `Cannot access a disposed object` error when running the following code (`MyClient` is a WCF client generate by a service reference in a C# project).

```
type Action =
    | Add
    | Update

let addStuff (myClient:MyClient) arg = async {
    let! response = myClient.AddAsync arg |> Async.AwaitTask
    return response.ID
}

let updateStuff (myClient:MyClient) arg = async {
    let! response = myClient.UpdateAsync arg |> Async.AwaitTask
    return response.ID
}

let doStuff arg =
    use myClient = new MyClient()
    match arg.Action with
    | Add -> arg |> addStuff myClient
    | Update -> arg |> updateStuff myClient

let args = [Add, Add, Update, Add]

let results =
    args
    |> List.map doStuff
    |> Async.Parallel
```

It seems the client is being disposed before I expect it to.  If I change `doStuff` to:

```
let doStuff arg = async {
    use myClient = new MyClient()
    return!
        match arg.Action with
        | Add -> arg |> addStuff myClient
        | Update -> arg |> updateStuff myClient
}
```

The return type of both functions is `Async<int>`.  Why is the client being disposed early in the first example?  I would think both examples are logically identical.  My understanding is that the `async` workflow is only necessary if you need to use the `!` bindings which I do not think is necessary in this case as the actual await is happening in the specific functions.

Comment: Looks like a `disposed closure access` case from Resharper analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `doStuff`:

```
let doStuff arg =
    use myClient = new MyClient()
    match arg.Action with
    | Add -> arg |> addStuff myClient
    | Update -> arg |> updateStuff myClient
```

You are passing `myClient` into an async function which captures the `MyClient` instance. However, when `doStuff` returns it calls `Dispose` on the `MyClient` instance and disposes the client. When your async method gets around to running it is using a disposed instance.

Making `doStuff` works because the dispose becomes part of the async workflow.

Another option would be to not `use` the `MyClient` instance but instean have `addStuff` and `updateStuff` create their own `MyClient` instance.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I figured.  I use this kind of pattern in lots of places.  Is there anything wrong with this pattern besides for `IDisposable`?  I think it is only a problem here because it disposes `myClient` as soon as it goes out of lexical scope.  For any other POCO or record, it should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

What the `async { ... }` block gives you in this case are two things:

1. It delays the execution of all the code inside it until the async computation is executed,
2. It handles the `use` keyword accordingly (i.e. the IDisposable will be disposed after the nested `addStuff`/`updateStuff` workflow executes).

As to whether the pattern you use is wrong - yes, it is.

F# async and C# async-await are two very different constructs with very different semantics, and experiences from one don't carry easily to the other.

C# async-await is a way of chaining `Tasks`. A `Task<'t>` is a future, that is, a container for a value of type `'t` that becomes available at a later time. The computation that produces that value is, by default, scheduled immediately to execute on a background thread, accessing the value is a blocking operation until that computation finishes, and further attempts to access it return a cached value.

On the other hand, F# `Async<'t>` is value that represents an abstract specification of a computation that, once executed, yields a value of type `'t`. The execution however is deferred to the caller - who can make a choice how (and if at all) to execute the computation. Unlike a task, async doesn't carry a value of type `'t` - each execution yields a new (and potentially different) value.

Going back to your sample:

```
let doStuff arg =
    use myClient = new MyClient()
    match arg.Action with
    | Add -> arg |> addStuff myClient
    | Update -> arg |> updateStuff myClient
```

What you have here is a function that does some work and returns an `Async<'t>` value to the caller. The caller is then free do to whatever they want with it - execute it, ignore it, or pass it further without executing.

The reason why it fails is because `myClient` is being disposed when `doStuff` returns - which is before the caller has a chance to execute the async.

The problem comes from the fact that this pattern you use splits execution of a particular piece of logic into two - one part executes when the function is called, the other when the async is executed, whereas the code is written with the intent that everything there executes as a single unit.

It is a pattern that invites more or less subtle bugs, even if in many cases there would be no easy to observe effects of this discrepancy - especially if async is unconditionally executed immediately after the function returns.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess this means the pattern I used should only be done in cases where you don't care if the earlier code runs immediately (which is a strange use case).  I agree is invites bugs.